# Send argument through PendingIntent of NavDeepLinkBuilder

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, android-bundle, android-architecture-navigation

I'm having some difficulties sending an argument through a `PendingIntent` of a notification using `NavDeepLinkBuilder`. I'm able to get the destination `Activity` to launch by clicking the notification, but the `Activity`'s `Intent` doesn't contain the argument value that I passed it through the `NavDeepLinkBuilder`. The `Intent` instead returns the `defaultValue` that I set in the nav graph - "noJobId".

**Notification creation**:

```
val notification =
    NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getString(R.string.notification_channel_id_new_job))
        ...
        .setContentIntent(
            NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
                .setComponentName(NewJobDetailsActivity::class.java)
                .setGraph(R.navigation.main_graph)
                .setDestination(R.id.newJobDetailsActivity)
                .setArguments(
                    NewJobDetailsActivityArgs.Builder()
                        .setJobId(event.jobId)
                        .build()
                        .toBundle()
                )
                .createPendingIntent()
        )
        .build()

notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
```

The `context` used in the notification is the `FirebaseMessagingService`.

**Destination `Activity` `onCreate()`**:

```
val jobId: String = NewJobDetailsActivityArgs.fromBundle(intent?.extras).jobId
```

**`main_graph.xml` Nav graph**:

```
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/jobsFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/jobsFragment"
        android:name=".ui.jobs.JobsFragment"
        android:label="JobsFragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_jobsFragment_to_newJobDetailsActivity"
            app:destination="@id/newJobDetailsActivity" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/historyFragment"
        android:name=".ui.history.HistoryFragment"
        android:label="HistoryFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name=".ui.profile.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="ProfileFragment" />

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/newJobDetailsActivity"
        android:name=".ui.job.NewJobDetailsActivity"
        android:label="activity_new_job_details"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_new_job_details">

        <argument
            android:name="jobId"
            android:defaultValue="noJobId" // just for testing
            app:argType="string" />

    </activity>

</navigation>
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? I have a feeling it's a bug with the Navigation component, but I'm not 100% sure yet. Curious if there's something I'm missing here.

**Dependencies**: android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha06, android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha06

**Plugin**: androidx.navigation.safeargs

Answer (score 10):

I posted this issue on Google's public issue tracker, and I received the following response:

> NavDeepLinkBuilder passes its args to a NavController to deep link
>   into a specific destination. Activity destinations are really more
>   exit points from a navigation graph than something that can/should be
>   deep linked to.

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118964253

The author of that quote recommends using `TaskStackBuilder` instead of `NavDeepLinkBuilder` when creating a `PendingIntent` whose destination is an `Activity`. Here's what I ended up going with:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getString(R.string.notification_channel_id_new_job))
    ...
    .setContentIntent(
        TaskStackBuilder.create(context).run {
            addNextIntentWithParentStack(Intent(context, DestinationActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtras(DestinationActivityArgs.Builder(jobId).build().toBundle())
            })
            getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }
    )
    .build()
```

This solution allows me to successfully deep link to a destination `Activity` while still being able to reference the args defined in the navigation graph for that `Activity` via the generated `DestinationActivityArgs` builder, and accessing the args from the destination `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method works.

This solution also correctly handles the cases when the app task is not in the 'recent apps' list, the app is in the foreground showing some other `Activity` or `Fragment`, or the app is in the foreground and already on the destination `Activity`. `addNextIntentWithParentStack()` properly handles up navigation, so clicking the up button from the destination `Activity` navigates back to the logical parent `Activity` as defined in the `AndroidManifest`.

It's a slight bummer that this solution isn't directly making use of that Navigation Architecture library to build the `PendingIntent`, but this feels like the best alternative.

Comment: I don't understand why more people aren't dropping in here with similar issues. I found the question relevant and the answer still applicable for notifications in nav version 2.1.0-rc01

Comment: @FredMedlin in 2.1.0 stable it appears to finally be working

Comment: Can you write it in Java?

Comment: @Adam still having the problem on version 2.3.5

Answer (score 1):

You can find all arguments that you send in the `arguments` variable of your Activity/Fragment.

Here's an example on how to retrieve a `String` argument set to the **PendingIntent** created by the **NavDeepLinkBuilder()** with key `EVENT_KEY` at your destination Activity/Fragment:

```
requireArguments().getString(YourClass.EVENT_KEY)?.let { it } ?: ""
```

Notice that our `getString()` call may return null in case the value we're looking for isn't there, so do make sure the `Bundle` you ultimately assign to `NavDeepLinkBulder().setArguments()` is populated the way you want it!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, my bundle was always returning null, this is what worked for me:

1. On my fragment I have a method that passes the bundle:

   ```
   notificationManager.sendNotification(
       requireArguments(), // This gets me the arguments supplied when the fragment in instantiated
       requireContext()
   )
   ```
2. On my notificationUtils my content Intent is:

   ```
   fun NotificationManager.sendNotification(
       bundle: Bundle,
       appContext: Context
   ) {
       val contentIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(appContext)
           .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java)
           .setGraph(R.navigation.navigation)
           .setDestination(R.id.detailsFragment)
           .setArguments(bundle)
           .createPendingIntent()

           // Rest of code to build the notification... 
   }
   ```
3. To test if the bundle was being passed correclty I logged as follows:

   ```
   Timber.d("The name is: ${bundle.getParcelable<Person>("Person")?.name}")
   ```